php to smarty boolean vars
i'm having trouble passing boolean values ​​from php to smarty:
php:
if ($Scad['inc']==TRUE){
   $inc = TRUE;
}else{
   $inc = FALSE;
}

smarty template:
{if $inc===true}
   {assign var='bg_color' value='cyano-background'}
{/if}

i get:
Warning: Trying to access array offset on null

what am i doing wrong?

(a) Is $Scad actually set to anything in php? (b) Are you calling $form->assign('inc', $inc); or equivalent anywhere so that smarty knows what $inc is?

yes I tried to report only the essentials... maybe I exaggerated, but I solved it anyway... I wasted hours and I didn't understand what was wrong (I'm new with smarty)... on the template the variable name was wrong (damn copy-paste) :)

I don't see any actual assignment happening in your php. Your php code (which btw is 5 lines that could easily be reduced to 1 since it simply copies the value to another variable without changing it) should look like:
$smarty->assign('inc', $Scad['inc']);

Where $smarty is your reference to CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton().
